# Инициализация массива в структуре

Tags: rust

Есть массив из 100 элементов в структуре:

```
struct S{
    state: [i32;100],
}
```

Нужно в конструкторе заполнить его последовательностью чисел от 1 до 100:

```
impl S{
    fn new() -> S{
        // что должно быть здесь?
    }
}
```

Comment: [здесь](https://www.joshmcguigan.com/blog/array-initialization-rust/), пожалуй, все варианты перечислены...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вам парочку вариантов, итоговый думаю выбирайте сами:

**1:** Предполагается что вы заполняете **все** элементы массива *(иначе не записанные элементы будут в неопределенном положении (иногда нули, иногда мусор:) )*

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::mem::MaybeUninit;
    let mut array: [usize; 32] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };
    // сейчас в array записаны неопределенные значения, обязательно запишите каждый элемент какими-либо данными

    for a in array.iter_mut() { // цикл по всем элементам массива
        *a = 1; // разыменовать ссылку a, и записать в нее значение 1
        // a - активный элемент цикла
    }
    println!("{:?}", array); // вывести значения в консоль
}
```

Playground: [Запуск](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=433aa645e07861ba1810c2e717a0769e)

**Плюсы:**

1. Максимальная производительность.
2. Современный вариант с **MaybeUninit**.

**Минусы:**

1. Использование **unsafe**, новичкам этот вариант лучше не советовать (вдруг что забудете).
2. Возня с **MaybeUninit**, раньше было проще с **std::mem::uninitialized()** но он объявлен deprecated.

**2:** Заполнение массива начальными значениями дабы в последствии изменить лишь некоторые элементы

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut array = [0usize; 32]; // инициализировать массив из 32 элементов и заполнить его нулями

    for a in array.iter_mut() { // цикл по всем элементам массива
        *a = 1; // разыменовать ссылку a, и записать в нее значение 1
        // a - активный элемент цикла
    }
    println!("{:?}", array); // вывести значения в консоль
}
```

Playground: [Запуск](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d94c74f8f95cdc9fbef0d877603b080b)

**Плюсы:**

1. Никаких **unsafe**, только **safe rust**!
2. В рамках одного стека(этой функции) компилятор способен привести ваш вариант кода в 1 вариант с максимальной производительностью.

**Минусы:**

1. При сложно запутанных действиях вас компилятор может не понять и сделать двойную инициализацию значения. (конечно вы потеряете незначительную производительность по сравнению с тем кодом который вы *наверное* будете писать)

**3:** Напролом, заполнение элементов изначально без возможности заполнения циклом

```rust
fn main() {
    let array: [usize; 32] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
    println!("{:?}", array);
}
```

Playground: [Запуск](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e945401702747fa3b54ebd5bbfa70c4f)

**Плюсы:**

1. Максимальное safe которую только можно представить.

**Минусы:**

1. Значения должны быть известны еще до инициализации массива